# Selecting item from Pick list and display in Flatlist

Tags: react-native, picker

I want to pick a "city" in the Picker and my Flatlist should display only restaurants from that city. So basically, if the user selects "city1" then the list should display only restaurants of that city.

Here is my current code, getRestaurants() function:

```
   async getRestaurants() {

    firebase.firestore().collection('restaurants').get().then(querySnapshot => {
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        this.setState({ dataRestaurants: data });
        console.log("printing picked city", this.state.city);

        if (this.state.city !== "all") {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.dataRestaurants.length; i++) {
                var arr = this.state.dataRestaurants[i];
                var arrStrng = JSON.stringify(arr);
                console.log("Looping through array of restaurants: " + arrStrng);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.dataRestaurants.length; i++) {
                var arr = this.state.dataRestaurants[i];
                var arrStrng = JSON.stringify(arr);
                console.log("Looping through array of restaurants: " + arrStrng);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is the rendering:

```
  <View>
                    <View >
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Picker Example</Text>
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={this.state.city}
                            style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}

                            onValueChange={(throttlemodeValue, throttlemodeIndex) =>
                                this.updateCity(throttlemodeValue)}
                        >
                            <Picker.Item label="All" value="all" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Prishtine" value="Prishtine" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Gjakove" value="Gjakove" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Prizren" value="Prizren" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Gjilan" value="Gjilan" />

                        </Picker>
                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> {"City =" + this.state.city}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View >
                        <FlatList
                            style={styles2.containerStyle}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.res_id}
                            data={this.state.dataRestaurants}
                            enableEmptySections={true}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderNativeItem(item)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flatlist-picker-data)

Maintain a selected city variable in state.Update it with the picker `onChange`, then from the changed state variable pick up the corresponding data from the state/props as

```
this.state.dataRestaurant[this.state.city]
```

Your flatlist looks like this.

```
<FlatList
        style={styles.flatList}
        keyExtractor={item => item.res_id}
        data={this.state.dataRestaurants[this.state.city]}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderNativeItem(item)}
      />
```

Comment: I was able to run it in my browser.Is the app not loading or it is not working as you wanted ?

Comment: no it is not loading at all actually, and currently I am not able to test it on my code because I am having some other trouble with some packages :/

Comment: nevermind, its working now! I will test it later in my code but seems ok for now :) thanks for the help

Comment: If it works for you please accept the answer to help others.Thanks !

Comment: btw where should I push the array I fetch from the server? Because you have divided all the cities into different arrays, how can I push each restaurant object to the respective city array in state?

Comment: Thakur, do you have any suggestion what to do about the above question?

Comment: You can restructure the data you are getting from server when saving in state.I just gave a rough idea about how to change things.